# How can I get inf2cat.exe to actually install

Tags: visual-studio

I have installed:
10.0.14393.0
10.0.15063.0
10.0.16299.0
10.0.17134.0
10.0.17763.0
10.0.18362.0
10.0.19041.0

The last 2 (18362 and 19041) I did just the other day so I know for a fact I left everything "checked" in the installer. But I can't find even a trace of inf2cat.exe. I even searched the entire c:/program files(x86)/Windows Kits/10/ directory. It's not in Program Files/Windows Kits/ either.

My coworker has it, so he gave me his copy, but when I run it (from C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.19041.0\x86, or C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\x86), it complains about missing dlls. No surprise there, since the SDK installer seems to think I don't need inf2cat, it probably thinks I don't need any of the dlls it needs either.

What would make the SDK installer NOT give me inf2cat.exe? My understanding is that if I want that tool, I need to install the SDK. Well, I've done that. No inf2cat.exe. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: It is a WDK tool, not SDK.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/download-the-wdk

Comment: Thanks, @HansPassant. Trying that now...

Comment: @HansPassant, that was exactly the issue. You have solved my problem - THANK YOU!